# What is the meaning of "docker ps -a"?

Tags: docker

Anyone who works with Docker regularly is familiar with the common commands `docker ps` and `docker ps -a`.

I know that `docker ps` lists all running containers in the Docker engine, but what does the "ps" actually mean?

I also know that `docker ps -a` has the effect of also listing containers that have stopped, but what does the `-a` actually mean?

Comment: `ps` is short for Process Status - https://www.journaldev.com/24613/linux-ps-command#:~:text=The%20ps%20command%2C%20short%20for,concurrently%20without%20affecting%20each%20other.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`-a` is short form for the `--all`. option This option will show all the containers both stopped and running.

`ps` is an abbreviation for "*p*rocess *s*tatus". Normally, `docker ps` only shows the running containers, but adding the `-a` option causes it to show *all* containers.

You can find more details in [the Docker "ps" options documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/).

Answer (score 4):

`ps` means “Process Status”, so `docker ps` basically shows all of the Docker processes actively running.

`docker ps` lists all containers that are up and running.

`-a` means all (both stopped and running) containers.

Answer (score 3):

The command [`docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) was created based on unix's [`ps` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html). Here, [`ps` is an abbreviation for "process status"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ps_(Unix)).

Translated to docker, `docker ps` lists containers. Executing `docker ps` lists all running containers, while executing `docker ps -a` (or `docker ps --all`) lists all containers.

Answer (score 2):

`docker ps` = `docker container list` = `docker container ls`

All commands above are aliases.

The command `docker ps` is very useful. For example:

- `docker container kill $(docker ps -q)` — Kill all running containers.
- `docker container rm $(docker ps -a -q)` — Delete all not running containers.